# Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server > send: publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, windows-8, ubuntu-14.04

I've launched an EC2 instance with Ubuntu 14 OS.

I'm trying to connect from a Windows 8 computer to my EC2 instance using PuTTY following the [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html), but when I click the Open button I receive the following error:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server
>   send: publickey)

I'm quite sure I've made everything right according to the instructions (the ppk file etc).

[This troubleshooting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingPuTTY) hasn't helped me because I have tried both ubuntu and root as username, e.g. ubuntu@ec2-12-345-678-90.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com

I've also seen many questions on SO with the same error, but in all of them the author missed something that I have not.

I have really no idea what to do. Really hope someone will manage to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend trying another SSH client such as MobaXterm, it supports pem

So you can run your command `ssh -i /path/to/key.pem ubuntu@IP`

Comment: It says the free edition has 12 sessions by maximum. What do they mean by that? Do they mean I can only connect to the server 12 times and then I will have to purchase the premium edition? https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html

Comment: @Alon that means you can have a maximum of 12 saved sessions. You can connect to your server as many time as you'd like have as many sessions opened as you'd like.